# How to remove element when clicking outside the element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom

I have created a dropdown menu for my web app and when clicking on a icon i'm opening my dropdown menu. I want to remove the dropdown menu when i click anywhere other than the dropdown menu. My current approach removes the element when clicking outside the element. But i cannot open the dropdown menu when clicking on the icon after that. How can i fix it?

```
class DropDown extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);

        this.state = {

            openmenu:false

        }

    };

    myFunction(e) {

        e.stopPropagation();

        this.setState({

            openmenu: !this.state.openmenu

        })

    render() {
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (!event.target.matches('myDropdown')) {

                document.getElementById('myDropdown2').remove();

            }
        }


        return (
            <div className="dropdown small_font" id="myDropdown" >

                <i className="fa fa-cog user_settings_icon" style={{marginTop: '6px'}} onClick={this.myFunction}
                   aria-hidden="true"></i>

                {this.state.openmenu?
                <div className="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown2">

                    <a className="dropdown_item"><i className="fa fa-trash-o margin_right10px" aria-hidden="true"></i>Delete</a>
                    <a className="dropdown_item"><i className="fa fa-flag-o margin_right10px" aria-hidden="true"></i>Report</a>

                </div>:null
                }
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

The error i'm getting when clicking on the icon for the second time

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

Comment: You are removing dropdown menu; why are u again trying to re-open it;

Or did it mis-interpret your words?

Comment: I heard you didn't get a proper answer? What can we do for you? Have you tried my approach?

Comment: @mersocarlin yh i got it to work using onBlur function

Comment: @CraZyDroid mark the correct answer or update your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to keep track of adding and removing click events on unmount and a solution that works across all browsers id recommend using a library. Ive used https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside and it works very well, heres a snippet.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import onClickOutside from "react-onclickoutside";

class MyComponent extends Component {
  handleClickOutside = evt => {
    // ..handling code goes here...
  };
}

export default onClickOutside(MyComponent);
```

If you dont want to use a library use the `onBlur`

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  handleClickOutside = evt => {
    // ..handling code goes here...
  };
  render(){
    <div onBlur={this.handleClickOutside}>
      <SomeChild />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Lastly your using React wrong, your using it as if it was jquery which it is not. you dont remove anything manually. You have state that you update when to close the dropdown and when to open it.

Comment: This is a good practice, without unnecessarily using external libraries that result in additional dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Using events such as `window.onclick` in `render` method is not a good practice since every time you update your state this event is going to be instantiated.

I also noticed you have created the state prop `openmenu` and `myFunction` but you not using them properly.

My suggestion is to attach DOM events in ReactJS's lifecycle events:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('onClick', this.myFunction)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  // Make sure to remove such event when your component is unmounted
  window.removeEventListener('onClick', this.myFunction)
}
```