# Close dropdown when clicking outside using javascript/reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I've created a drop down menu and open the menu when the user clicks on the menu icon. I have done this using react states. How can i close the dropdown menu when user clicks outside the menu element?

Dropdown menu

```
class DropDown extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);


        this.state = {

            openmenu:false

        }

    };

    myFunction(e) {

        e.stopPropagation();

        this.setState({

            openmenu: !this.state.openmenu

        })


    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="dropdown small_font" id="myDropdown" onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown} onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}>
                {/*<img src={settings} onClick={this.myFunction} className="user_settings_icon"></img>*/}
                <i className="fa fa-cog user_settings_icon" style={{marginTop: '6px'}} onClick={this.myFunction}
                   aria-hidden="true"></i>
                {this.state.openmenu?
                <div className="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown2">
                    {/*<div id="myDropdown" className={this.props.actionDropDownCSS}>*/}
                    <a className="dropdown_item"><i className="fa fa-trash-o margin_right10px" aria-hidden="true"></i>Delete</a>
                    <a className="dropdown_item"><i className="fa fa-flag-o margin_right10px" aria-hidden="true"></i>Report</a>
                    <a className="dropdown_item"><i className="fa fa-minus-square-o margin_right10px" aria-hidden="true"></i>Unfriend</a>
                    <a className="dropdown_item"><i className="fa fa-sign-out margin_right10px" aria-hidden="true"></i>Leave group</a>
                </div>:null
                }
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: didnt u ask the same qn this morning?  what happened to that ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove element when clicking outside the element in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47428348/how-to-remove-element-when-clicking-outside-the-element-in-javascript)

Comment: i didn't get a answer that helped me @RajkumarSomasundaram

Comment: @CraZyDroiD I asked for ur insight on that qn. u didnt respond ; so i moved on..

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onBlur() event on the icon and write a function to close the menu

Something like this would work

```
this.closeMenu(){
    this.setState({
            openmenu: false
        })
}
<i onBlur={this.closeMenu} />
```

Answer (score 0):

To achive this easily, you can use libraries like `react-bootstrap`, `antd` etc.

```js
import React from "react";
import { DropdownButton, Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";

const CustomDropdown = () => (
  <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Dropdown button">
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
  </DropdownButton>
);

export default CustomDropdown;
```